# AWS Managed Microsoft AD LDAP

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, ldap, apache-ds, aws-directory-service

I have AWS managed MS AD standup and running. Created a jump node and joined the domain. I was able to execute ldp.exe and establish connection to one of my AD controller whose address is like (port 389): COMPUTERNAME.MYADNAME

I am trying to connect to same Domain controller from ApacheDS on my laptop, but getting error message, can't connect.

I looked at security groups attached to DC and all relevant ports are open. Any idea what am I missing?

This seems like connectivity or some firewall block issue, but couldn't find where it is.

Comment: Check you have an internet gateway attached to your VPC, and a route from the VPC to the internet gateway.

Comment: @Tim Yes, all other traffic to other instances in same VPC working fine.

Comment: What diagnostics have you done? Can you ping the instance? Can you connect to say a web server on port 80? Can you connect to it in any way? Have you tried connecting from another instance in the same VPC? Have you checked the instance firewall? You need to give us more to be able to help you.

Comment: I have a webserver in same VPC AD deployed to. I can ping, reach out on port 80, SSH into this webserver. --> This confirms that there is no VPC level traffic block. I made sure port 389 also open in security group so that LDAP can talk on that port, but no luck to LDAP to AD.

Comment: Then my best is it's a firewall at one end or the other. As I suggested, set up a spot instance and try to connect from that, if it works that suggests it's a firewall or problem on your client side.

Comment: Technically speaking AWS can talk to an IDP such as LDAP over a TCP port.  There is no way you can technically open that port for security reasons.  Check if that is the case.